# Цвет ссылок

Tags: html, css

Не пойму, почему так получается. В верстке прописаны два дива

```
<div id="enter">
    <a href="">
        Текст ссылки 1
    </a>
</div>
<div id="reg-button">
    <a href="">
        Текст ссылки 2
    </a>
</div>
```

Для ссылок в разных дивах заданы разные стили

```
#enter a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #5e7743;
    font: 13px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times serif;
    margin-left: 105px;
    text-align: right;
}
#reg-button a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #fffcee;
    font: italic 26px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times serif;
    line-height: 2.5;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

в итоге получается, что ссылка в диве с id="enter" выводится цветом, который задан для дива с id="reg-button" (но при этом остается подчеркнутой, а для ссылки в диве reg-button задано `text-decoration: none;`)

Почему так получается?

Comment: Залейте на сайт какой-нибудь страничку, в фаербаге поковыряю и ответ дам. Так сложно понять в чем причина. Если описание верное, то это во-преки законов физики. Может кэшируется что у Вас там? В общем ссылку давайте.

Comment: спасибо, ниже уже дали ответ на вопрос)

Comment: Отметьте его тогда как правильный

Answer (score 7, accepted):

То что вы прописали через запяутю **a:visited, a:hover** и т.д. - это значит правило для всех ссылок на странице

```
#enter a:link, #enter a:visited, #enter a:hover, #enter a:active {
    // ....
}
#reg-button a:link, #reg-button a:visited, #reg-button a:hover, #reg-button a:active {
    / ....
}
```

А вообще, достаточно

```
#reg-button a {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: вы спасли мне рассудок)))

Comment: Плизззз ))